# Is there an API to make use of the Windows Speech Recognition's MouseGrid feature?

Tags: windows, api, speech-recognition, pinvoke

I'm hoping to use Microsoft's built in Mouse Grid feature.  The feature is typically used via the Windows Speech Recognition feature to systematically narrow down where to click the screen via your voice.

Does anyone know if the MouseGrid feature is exposed in any of Microsoft's APIs?

This is how the feature looks during use:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  It's entirely part of the Windows Speech Recognition app.